# What is the FacebookSession equivalent in FB PHP SDK 5?

Tags: php, facebook, session, sdk

I used to use this for retreiving a session back when I used FB PHP SDK 4, but I'm unclear what I need to do for 5.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET );
return new FacebookSession( FACEBOOK_APP_ID . '|' . FACEBOOK_SECRET );
```

I'm aware of the example listed on https://www.sammyk.me/upgrading-the-facebook-php-sdk-from-v4-to-v5

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id'     => '{app-id}',
  'app_secret' => '{app-secret}',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4',
]);
return $fb;
```

I'm completely new to this type of setup and am stumbling in the dark, but these two pieces of code don't seem to return the same thing. Does anyone have a suggestion how I can return what was being returned with FacebookSession now in PHP SDK 5?

Comment: It's an XY-problem: why do you need to get it in the very first place?

Comment: The SDK v5 doesn’t use such a session class any more. Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted, it has easy examples.